# Cloudflare + Amazon S3 - for some reason encrypting my page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I set up my site through Cloudflare and Amazon S3.

[image: Cloudflare settings]

And I'm pretty sure I did it right. But for some reason when I visit my site at [ch.ris.li](http://ch.ris.li) all I get is this:

[image: gobldygook]

any idea why?

**UPDATE**

After doing like 10 hard refreshes in quick succession it loads the page as it is supposed to be, and then after a few more it does this again.

Comment: Your index page, somehow, has an *empty* `Content-Encoding:` value.  At some point, the content is getting double-gzipped.  If you gzipped it before storing it in S3, then set `Content-Encoding: gzip`; otherwise, remove that entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to @michael-sqlbot.

Cloudflare automatically gzips resources but it'll play nicely if your resources are already gzipped. So I added `activate :gzip` to my config.rb and like magic it works again!